# How can I get s3's view of latency?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see that [access logs show a bunch of stats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html), but there is no mention of latency.

Is there any way to get **from aws** how long from the time it receives an s3 request to the time it finishes sending a response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Review the [Log Format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) specificaction.

> **Total Time**
>
> The number of milliseconds the request was in flight from the server's perspective. This value is measured from the time your request is received to the time that the last byte of the response is sent. Measurements made from the client's perspective might be longer due to network latency.
>
> **Turn-Around Time**
>
> The number of milliseconds that Amazon S3 spent processing your request. This value is measured from the time the last byte of your request was received until the time the first byte of the response was sent.

Turn-Around Time is the same as TTFB.  Total time is largely dependent on the bandwidth delay product between the client and S3, because S3 serves up the responses with multiple megabit per second capacity.

Either S3 Transfer Acceleration or using CloudFront in front of S3 can improve download times for more distant browsers, because both of those services keep the traffic on the AWS "edge" network for most of the distance between the bucket and the browser, and CloudFront optionally caches objects near where they are frequently downloaded.